# CSS add display block all items except some items

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have this div where I'm displaying some images, Can I add `display: none` to all items except first, second, and third?

```
  <ng-template #customDayTemplateHover let-day="day" class="cal-time-events">
<div class="user-day-off-template" *ngFor="let dayOff of dayOffsArrayDayView">
  <div class="users">
    <img class="user-img" src="{{dayOff.photo}}" alt="">
    <div class="name-type">
      <span class="type">{{dayOff.type}}</span>
      <span class="name">{{dayOff.employee_name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes you can use `nth-child` property

Comment: I have tried use that function but I don't know how many items might be there

Comment: While you can do this using `nth`, why not setting different classes?

Comment: @Lain because the items I'm displaying by using for loop

Comment: I do not see the issue with `for-loop` and setting classes. First, second and third are always going to be first, second and third, no matter how many items you have.

Comment: @Lain I just edited the question please check it

Comment: Should tag it as angular I assume. It works fine using css `nth`. Was just curious about it.

Comment: @Lain sorry I forgot to add (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [functional notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#functional_notation) with the [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector to do this.

For example :

```
ul li:nth-of-type(1n+4) { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the nth-child selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the items I'm displaying with for loop and i don't know how many items can be there

Answer (score 1):

you can add attribute class to define a property css: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp

You can do a validate to know in what element going was this class